# Is there a way to make HTML reusable blocks?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to reuse html block contents web app (I use jquery and bootstrap).

I have a big html block like this:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="distMotors">Drawing size</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 0px">
            <label style="width:5em; float:left; padding-top: 8px;"
                    class="control-label visible-xs" for="drawingWidth">Width</label>
            <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 10em">
                <input disabled type="number" id=drawingWidth min="10" max="500"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="150" data-error="Set a number between 10 and 500.">
                <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <span class="col-sm-1 hidden-xs"style="text-align: center; padding: 7px 0px">X</span>
        <label style="width:5em; float:left; padding-top: 8px;"
                class="control-label visible-xs" for="drawingHeight">Height</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5" style="padding: 0px">
            <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 10em">
                <input disabled id=drawingHeight type="number" min="10" max="500"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="150" data-error="Set a number between 10 and 500.">
                <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="help-block">Width and height of the drawing on the showcase.</span>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are several blocks like this one in my page, so my html file is going to be a mess.
I am looking for a library or a small framework to do something like this:

- first I define my html block structure and apparence;
- then I use it several times, and I change only interresting values, like `id`, `placeholder`, etc.

Is there something like this?

Comment: Custom tag library. Google it.

Comment: What language/technology do you use for your web app? (MVC, c#/vb, php, jsp, asp.net)

Comment: It's a small web app, I use ony bootstrap and jquery. I will maybe use AngularJS if it going bigger.

Comment: @Takendarkk Thank you! But custom tag library seems to be for JSP pages and I don't use this techno for my project. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use jQuery to copy the top div, change some attributes inside and then insert it elsewhere on your page. Depending on what back-end stack you have, most of them also support partial views which are built exactly for this type of scenario.

jQuery:

```
var element = $('.row.form-group').clone();
element.children('.input-group').attr('id', new_id); // change attribute
$('.new_parent').append(element); // .new-parent is the class of the element to which you want to append the copy
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this short solution!

Comment: Well, I tried this and it's better, but in fact, my html file now contains sometimes elements in html, sometimes in JS and I don't like this.

Comment: Do you know any lib/framework to do this in html, using special tags ?

Comment: Check out handlebars.js  or mustache.js for basic HTML templating. If you are looking for a component framework check out react.js. React is more than just templating but that is a big part of it. You have to build your app in it using a special syntax for html inside of javascript, called JSX. For certain applications (like facebook) it can be useful.

Comment: Just wanted to add in response to mixing html in js, in this case you are only using JS to generate new html, not really defining it there so i think that is reasonable. If you were to change the original html in the html file the JS would not need to be updated (unless of course it's the classes you are using to copy but that could be standardized). So in this case the JS is just an engine and is not mixing 'view' with 'logic.' Unless you are using purely static content you will at some point have to generate html from JS or server side.

Comment: Is it possible to copy from one page and paste into another page?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a multidimensional array containing your ids, placeholder text, etc. And loop through to create your form.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gue9ryqo/

HTML

```
<div id='contents'></div>
```

JQUERY

```
var arr = [
    ['one', 'placeholder1'],
    ['two', 'placeholder2'],
    ['three', 'placeholder3']
    ];
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   $('#contents').append(
       "<div>"+
        "<label>Label</label>"+
            "<input type='text' id='"+arr[i][0]+"' placeholder='"+arr[i][1]+"'/>"+
       "</div>"
       );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you cshanno!
It works very well, however I am a MVC user and I don't want to make html content in JS like this.